# ¿ como se usa un garbage colector?

Tags: python

estaba viendo lo que es el garbage colector y me genero un par de dudas, lo que entendí fue que te libera espacio en la memoria de objetos y variables que ya no se van a usar, ¿ pero como se usa un garbage colector en python ? no entiendo como debe introducirse en el código o donde debería ir un garbage colector, lo había escuchado en otros lenguajes y si esto optimiza una aplicación me interesaría aprender a usarlo.

Comment: No sé qué habrás estado leyendo, pero desde luego lo entendiste un poco mal, creo. El GC (GarbageCollector) trabaja él solito sin que tengas que introducirlo tú ni nada. Digamos que tú creas un objeto de clase X, y luego te vas a otra parte de tu código y la referencia a ese objeto se queda *muerta*, sin nada más de uso. Pues al cabo de un tiempo, python (y cualquier otro lenguaje con GC) eliminará esa instancia de la memoria, puesto que no sirve para nada ya. Como ves, mientras no mantengas referencias a instancias que ya no usas en tu clase actual, el GC hará su trabajo él solito!

Comment: @Benito-B estaba leyendo esto de la documentacion oficial [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) no sabia que era automatico

Comment: La interfaz existe para permitirte *controlar* el GC... pero no suele ser necesario. Habrá casos específicos que lo necesiten, pero personalmente, no conozco ninguno

Comment: El GC puede ser manual en algunas situaciones. En Micropython, por ejemplo, que corre en SBC como ESP8266 y ESP32, puedes detener el GC cuando necesitas hacer operaciones con un timming preciso, evitando que GC se ponga a trabajar entremedio e interfiera.

Comment: ahh entonces se podria decir que el garbage colector es automático y en determinados casos se puede usar manualmente que interesante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque el recolector de basura funciona automáticamente en Python y no debería ser algo de lo que te tengas que preocupar, conocer algunos detalles de cómo Python gestiona la memoria pueden serte útiles (aún sin usar nunca la interfaz `gc`).

En python **todos** los datos son en realidad objetos y ocupan un espacio en memoria mayor de lo que cabría esperar en otros lenguajes, debido a que no sólo se guarda el dato en sí, sino también meta-información acerca del mismo (su tipo entre otras cosas).

Por ejemplo, cuando usas un entero en tu programa como aquí:

```
a = 10000
```

el intérprete necesita reservar un espacio en memoria donde poder guardar un objeto de tipo `int` que contiene el dato 10000. Lo que ocupe el objeto depende un poco de la implementación de Python con la que estés trabajando. En CPython por ejemplo ocuparía 28 bytes. En otros lenguajes el entero es un dato de 32 bits (o de 64, según la arquitectura) por lo que ocuparía tan sólo 4 bytes (u 8, según la arquitectura).

Una variable no es más que una referencia (un puntero si prefieres llamarlo así) a la dirección de memoria donde está realmente el dato.

La memoria que se ha reservado para contener el entero 10000 permanecerá ocupada **mientras haya alguna referencia** que se refiera a ese dato. Internamente el intérprete mantiene un contador de referencias que va actualizando con cada asignación. Por ejemplo en este momento el contador de referencias sería 1, porque hemos asignado el dato a una variable `a`, y por tanto hay una referencia apuntando a él.

Si seguidamente haces por ejemplo:

```
b = a
```

Entonces el intérprete creará una variable `b` y copiará a ella la referencia que había en `a`, de modo que en este momento hay **dos referencias** al mismo objeto. Tanto `a` como `b` se están refiriendo al mismo objeto. Su contador de referencias vale `2`.

Si seguidamente haces por ejemplo:

```
a = a + 1
```

entonces ocurren varias cosas:

- Se crea un nuevo objeto de tipo `int` para contener el resultado de la operación (otros 28 bytes que son necesarios)
- Se inicializa ese nuevo objeto `int` con el valor 10001 (que es el resultado de la operación)
- Se cambia la referencia que había en `a` (que apuntaba al entero 10000) para que ahora apunte al entero 10001.
- Como consecuencia de esta asignación, el entero 10001 incrementa su contador de referencias que pasa a valer 1 (la referencia `a` apunta a él) y el entero 10000 *decrementa* su contador de referencias, ya que `a` ha dejado de apuntar a él. El contador de referencias de 10000 vale 1 (porque `b` todavía apunta a él).

Si finalmente haces algo como:

```
b = "Hola"
```

Eso creará un nuevo objeto en memoria de tipo `str`, inicializado con la cadena `"Hola"`, y hará que la referencia `b` cambie su valor para pasar a apuntar a este objeto. Como consecuencia el objeto `str` tiene su contador de referencias a 1, **y el contador de referencias de 10000 pasa a cero**, pues `b` ha dejado de apuntar a él.

Entonces el intérprete ejecutará el recolector de basura para eliminar los objetos cuyo contador de referencias es 0. En este caso se liberará el objeto `int` que valía 10000, liberándose así 28 bytes de memoria.

**Moralejas** de lo anterior:

1. Las operaciones son más complicadas de lo que aparentaban en la superficie. Si vienes de un lenguaje como C, te habrá sorprendido el follón que se ha montado para un simple `a=a+1`. En C lo que ocurría simplemente es que la posición de memoria en que estaba guardado el 10000 se sobreescribe y pasa a contener un 10001. En Python no, pues los enteros son inmutables. Un 10000 siempre será un 10000 (mientras exista)
2. La memoria no se va a liberar mientras tengas variables que se refieren a ese objeto. Por tanto una posible forma de liberar memoria cuando andes escaso de ella puede ser **borrar la referencia**.

   La instrucción `del  a`, por ejemplo, elimina la referencia llamada `a`, decrementando así el contador de referencias del objeto al que apuntaba. Considera este ejemplo:

   ```
   >>> a = 10000
   >>> del a
   >>> a
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'a' is not defined
   ```

   La primera instrucción reservará 28 bytes para el entero 10000 y la referencia `a` apuntará a ese entero. Su contador de referencias será por tanto 1. La línea `del a` elimina la variable `a` (que pasa a ser no definida como se comprueba seguidamente). El entero al que `a` apuntaba pasará a tener un contador de referencias cero, y será por tanto liberado por el recolector de basura.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Es bastante sencillo;

```
import gc
............
gc.collect() #cuando quieras hacer la limpieza
```