# cambiar un array a list ocupa más memoria

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

quisiera saber si al momento de tener un array y lo convierto en list, el array se elimina o aun queda ocupando memoria. Por ejemplo:

```
Array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
Array1 = Array1.tolist()
```

Cuando cambio el Array1 a lista, ¿el array se borra y ahora ocupa memoria la lista?

Comment: Si tolist devuelve una lista, si. Mientras haya referencias activas el objeto sigue en memoria ,  puedes usar el Garbage collector de phyton.

Comment: Si `Array1` era la única referencia que tenías al objeto array, y has reasignado `Array1`, entonces el objeto array se habrá quedado sin referencias que apunten a él, por lo que automáticamente el recolector de basura de python lo eliminará de memoria. Si tienes otras referencias apuntando al array en cambio no será eliminado hasta que todas esas otras referencias dejen de apuntar a él (puedes eliminar una referencia con `del nombre`). Más detalles sobre el garbage collector en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/418644/7123)

Comment: De cualquier forma, respondiendo al título de la pregunta, la lista ocupará más memoria que el array porque usan modelos de almacenamiento muy diferentes (el array usa datos del mismo tipo que ocupan direcciones consecutivas de memoria)